# Error al traerme los datos del backend

Tags: php, html5

Hola estoy intentando traerme a través de las variables de sesión, los datos del usuario logueado para en una vista en HTML con php actualizar sus datos (código adjuntado). La cosa es que me da error y no consigo como solucionarlo. Dejo aquí los errores y el código correspondiente.

Errores:

**Notice**:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in **C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\edit_profile.php** on line **36**

**Notice**:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in **C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\edit_profile.php** on line **43**

**Notice**:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in **C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\edit_profile.php** on line **52**

**Notice**:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in **C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\edit_profile.php** on line **59**

Código edit_profile:

```
<?php
    require('php/conexion.php');

    // Mantiene la sesión iniciada
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }

    $id = $_SESSION['id'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM web_users WHERE id = '$id'";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min_1.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h3 style="text-align:center">MODIFICAR REGISTRO</h3>
            </div>

            <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="php/editar-usuario.php" autocomplete="off">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nombre" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nombre</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php echo $row['nombre']; ?>" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nombre" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Usuario</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuario" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" value="<?php echo $row['usuario']; ?>" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo $row['email']; ?>"  required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="telefono" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Telefono</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="telefono" name="mobile" placeholder="Telefono" value="<?php echo $row['mobile']; ?>" >
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="telefono" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Contraseña</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contraseña" name="passwd" placeholder="Contraseña">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-default">Regresar</a>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Archivo conexion base de datos:

```
<?php

    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'prueba');

    if($mysqli->connect_error){

        die('Error en la conexion' . $mysqli->connect_error);

    }
?>
```

Comment: Empieza a depurar: pon un `var_dump($row);` y dinos qué muestra. Parece que la consulta está fallando  o puede que la conexión no sea válida o la variable conexión no se llame `$mysqli` ... confírmanos esos pasos previos que son el ABC de la depuración en este caso.

Comment: He hecho el var_dump($row) justo debajo del $row y me aparecere esto:
`Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\edit_profile.php on line 9
NULL`

NULL sería el var_dump

Comment: El problema es que `$_SESSION['id']` devuelve `NULL`, por lo que el resultado de la consulta también está vacío. Haz  `var_dump($_SESSION);` para ver si realmente existe el id en la sesión.

Comment: Depura la sesión como te indica @OdeiAlba. Y si tiene datos para la clave `id`, entonces verifica el error propio de la consulta con `var_dump($mysqli->error);`

Comment: el `var_dump($_SESSION)` me devuelve esto:

`array(4) { ["loggedin"]=> bool(true) ["usuario"]=> string(7) "juanele" ["start"]=> int(1620288513) ["expire"]=> int(1620288813) }`

Comment: el `var_dump($mysqli->error);` me ha devuelto esto:

`string(0) ""`

Comment: Como podrás apreciar no hay una clave id en la sesión, por tanto no estarías recuperando nada aquí: `$id = $_SESSION['id'];`. Entoces, debes proveer el id en la sesión o filtrar por `usuario`, eso ya depende del contexto de tu código.

Comment: Pero es que aun filtrando por usuario, cambiando `$usuario = $_SESSION['usuario']`, me sigue devolviendo string 0 y no entiendo el porque.
El usuario que registre, se me registra bien en la base de datos, con su id, nombre, usuario, movil, email y contraseña. Cuando logueo, también lo hace bien pero al editar que salgan los campos rellenados no me los trae y no consigo arreglarlo, porque podra ser?

Comment: ¿Cómo estás escribiendo la consulta SQL cuando intentas filtrar por `usuario`?

Comment: He adjuntado el código registrar-usuario, checklogin y la conexion a parte del edit_profile, que es el primero.

La consulta la estoy realizando así:
`$usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM web_users WHERE usuario = '$usuario'";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);` archivo edit_profile

Comment: El problema aquí es que la consulta no funciona (no trae datos). Agregar más archivos en este caso es descentrarse del problema. Hay que determinar por qué esa consulta no trae datos simplemente, yendo a depurar directamente sin perderte en otros detalles. ¿Estás seguro de que en tu tabla hay un usuario `juanele`? Prueba a ejecutar esta consulta en la base de datos directamente: **`SELECT * FROM web_users WHERE usuario = 'juanele'`**

Comment: Si, eso lo he comprobado y me devuelve el usuario juanele que esta ya registrado con todos sus datos. Eso me funciona bien

Comment: OK. Al cambiar la consulta a esto: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM web_users WHERE usuario = '$usuario'";` ¿qué devuelve el `var_dump($row);` ? Supongo que  mantuviste esa depuración, ¿no?

Comment: Ese var_dump lo que me devuelve es NULL

Comment: Entonces hay algo que no cuadra aquí. Si tú dices que esta consulta: `SELECT * FROM web_users WHERE usuario = 'juanele'` ejecutada directamente en el SGBD trae datos, y que luego esta `$sql = "SELECT * FROM web_users WHERE usuario = '$usuario'";` ejecutada en PHP NO trae datos. Significa que: o bien en el contexto de PHP estás conectando a **otra base de datos** o que la sesión no tiene realmente el usuario `juanele` ... ¿Mantuviste también el `var_dump($mysqli->error);` y no muestra ningún error?

Comment: el `var_dump($mysqli->error)` muestra el mensaje **string(0) ""**, como que no le esta llegando nada. La base de datos se llama prueba como se ve en el archivo de conexion y la tabla es web_users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como has indicado en los comentarios, la variable de sesión no contiene el valor `id`, sino `usuario`. Sabiendo esto, lo único que tienes que hacer es buscar el usuario mediante el nombre de usuario en vez del id:

```
$usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM web_users WHERE usuario = '$usuario'";
```

Tu código completo quedaría así:

```
<?php
    require('php/conexion.php');

    // Mantiene la sesión iniciada
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }

    $usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM web_users WHERE usuario = '$usuario'";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min_1.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h3 style="text-align:center">MODIFICAR REGISTRO</h3>
            </div>

            <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="php/editar-usuario.php" autocomplete="off">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nombre" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nombre</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php echo $row['nombre']; ?>" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nombre" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Usuario</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuario" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" value="<?php echo $row['usuario']; ?>" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo $row['email']; ?>"  required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="telefono" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Telefono</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="telefono" name="mobile" placeholder="Telefono" value="<?php echo $row['mobile']; ?>" >
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="telefono" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Contraseña</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contraseña" name="passwd" placeholder="Contraseña">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-default">Regresar</a>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lo he hecho y tampoco lo hace. Y en los inputs del formulario me sale en todos este error:
**<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\edit_profile.php</b> on line <b>38</b><br />**

Comment: El error te sale dentro de los inputs?

Comment: @jdmm Que te devuelve `var_dump($sql);` justo después de crear la variable? Y `var_dump($row);`?

Comment: el error me sale dentro de los inputs, si. Justo despues de crear la variable sql, el var_dump me devuelve esto: `string(44) "SELECT * FROM web_users WHERE id = 'juanele'"`.
el var_dump de row despues de crearla me devuelve esto:
`NULL`

Comment: Y estás seguro de que las credenciales de la conexión a la base de datos son correctas?

Comment: Si, es localhost, porque es xampp, root, que es el usuario, sin contraseña porque no le he puesto, y la base de datos es prueba

Comment: @jdmm ¿no ves que la consulta está mal? `SELECT * FROM web_users WHERE id = 'juanele'` estás filtrando en base a la columna id, mientras que usas el nombre del usuario como criterio.

Comment: @jdmm Después de tanta vuelta no me había dado cuenta de eso. Lo ha dicho A. Cedano. No has cambiado la columna a la que estás haciendo la consulta. (Como te he mencionado ya en la respuesta) Tienes que cambiar `id = '$usuario'` por `usuario = '$usuario'`

Comment: Ahora ya si me funciona. Pero la cosa es, que ayer probé de esa manera y tampoco me iba, salia siempre el ultimo que habia iniciado sesion y no entedia el porque. Ahora hago lo que me habeis dicho y funciona. 
Pero cuando edito los datos de ese usuario y doy en guardar lo hace de forma correcta y me redirecciona como le he puesto a su panel de control. Y si digo de volver a entrar a editar perfil me salta con el error:
`<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\edit_profile.php</b> on line <b>40</b><br />` como si no esta logeado

Comment: @jdmm Eso es por que le has cambiado el valor en la base de datos, pero no en la sesión. Por lo que estás buscando en la base de datos un usuario que ya no existe. Para que te siga funcionando, tienes que cambiar en la sesión el valor de usuario por el nuevo. Pero eso ya es un problema diferente.
Por favor, si la respuesta te ha resultado de ayuda, márcala como útil y como respuesta correcta.

Comment: Esta marcada, pero entonces, ¿para mandar los datos actualizados a la sesión como sería?. He estado mirando y para mantener la sesión en todas las páginas que tengo es poner esto: `// Mantiene la sesión iniciada
 if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
 }`
o por lo menos donde lo visto el que estaba haciendo algo parecido lo ha hecho así y le ha funcionado

Comment: @jdmm El problema no es que la sesión deje de estar iniciada, sino que el valor de `$_SESSION['usuario']` sigue siendo el mismo, pero el valor de la base de datos ha cambiado.

Comment: En eso te entiendo lo que me quieres decir, pero en php tendré que pasarle ese cambio actualizado y la unica manera que puede que sirva es volviendo a realizar una consulta?@OdeiAlba